# CSS div width visually inaccurate

Tags: html, css

I have several divs, each 2px wide and they dont look the same (depending on their position). Although they are placed on full pixel, their width looks different. This is the problem in all browsers. Is this something that can be fixed?

```css
.a{
  position:relative;
  width:300px;
  height:10px;
  background:#ccc;
}
.b1{
  position:absolute;
  left:50px;
  width:2px;
  height:100%;
  background:blue;
}
.b2{
  position:absolute;
  left:100px;
  width:2px;
  height:100%;
  background:blue;
}
.b3{
  position:absolute;
  left:150px;
  width:2px;
  height:100%;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
<div class="b1"></div>
<div class="b2"></div>
<div class="b3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: the blue lines look the same width to me

Comment: Can you attach screenshot of the snippet? Just to see how it looks on your monitor. It looks fine in my browser.

Comment: I see the issue now. `.b2` is larger on my screen. It is not significant - but definately present. This occurs at every scaling option and zoom level in several browsers. My guess is that it may be related to calculation of `px` and inaccuracies in the floating point calculation. Very interested to see if someone smarter than me can reproduce and explain.

Comment: When you log the computed widths of each of these elements, does the browser claim they’re all the same size or does it acknowledge differences? I can’t reproduce on iPad, but my computer’s turned off now until tomorrow, so I can’t easily check myself.

Comment: Computed widths show the same.

Comment: @Nathan Fries Yes, that is the problem, I forgot to explain enough, but I have my browser scalled up a bit. Its really annoying to see such issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the first "bar" is 50px from the start and then the distance between the bars decreases by a little, it is because you do not include the width of the bar in the offset of the 2nd and 3rd "bar":

```css
.a{
  position:relative;
  width:300px;
  height:10px;
  background:#ccc;
}
.b1{
  position:absolute;
  left:50px;
  width:2px;
  height:100%;
  background:blue;
}
.b2{
  position:absolute;
  left:102px;
  width:2px;
  height:100%;
  background:blue;
}
.b3{
  position:absolute;
  left:154px;
  width:2px;
  height:100%;
  background:blue;
}
[class^="b"]:after {
  content: '50px';
  width: 50px; height: 2px;
  position: absolute; bottom: -2px; left: -50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px; font-family: sans-serif;
  background: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
<div class="b1"></div>
<div class="b2"></div>
<div class="b3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not address the issue OP is seeing

Comment: @Nathan Fries seems like it now, after lengthy discussion =)...wasn't that clear what OP meant when I wrote the answer, plus, what I fixed above was actually the ONLY inconsistency I could find with any widths not being the same...the blue lines were perfectly fine...but the distance between them wasn't... Now it seems quite obvious what's going on when OP stated "I forgot to explain enough, but I have my browser scaled up a bit." (a.k.a. zoom)